# How to auto configure Cloudera Manager?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I have created a few scripts that allow me to automate a vast majority of installing CDH5 & Cloudera Manager v5. The issue is that each time the cluster is spun up, I have to configure cloudera manager via the GUI wizard. How would one configure cloudera manager so that the GUI setup wizard could be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudera Manager has a full REST API that allows you to programmatically do anything that can do through the UI. API details are here: http://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/